# Evaluating an integral in calculus III

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Please can someone explain what happened after step 3 , in this upload image of the exercise
[image: exercise] 
Please make it clear how the "1/2" came in step 4 , and why we are subtracting the integrals

Comment: Partial fractions.

Comment: Google Partial Fractions.

Comment: If this is Calculus III, what is Calculus I?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The technique used is called partial fractions.  $$\frac{1}{(u-1)(u+1)} = \dfrac{A}{u-1} + \dfrac B{u + 1}$$ From this, we can solve for $A, B$ by noting that $$A(u+1) + B(u - 1) = 1\tag{1}$$

This problem is rather "nice" in that we can solve for $A, B$ by letting $u$ take on the values of $1$, $-1$.

Letting $u = 1$ in $(1)$ gives us $A(1+1) +B(1-1) = 2A = 1 \iff A = \frac 12$.

Letting $u = -1$ in $(1)$ gives us $0A -2B = 1 \iff B = -\frac 12$.

Hence, we have that $$\begin{align} \int \dfrac{du}{(u - 1)(u+1)} & = \int \dfrac{1/2}{u-1} + \dfrac{-1/2}{u+1} \,du \\ \\ &= \dfrac{1}2\int \left(\frac 1{u - 1} - \frac 1{u+1}\right)\,du\\ \\ &= \dfrac 12\left[\int\dfrac {du}{x-1} - \int \frac{du}{x+1}\right]\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to observe that
$$
\frac{1}{(u-1)(u+1)}=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{u+1}{(u-1)(u+1)}-\frac{u-1}{(u-1)(u+1)}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{u-1}-\frac{1}{u+1}\right).
$$